# Django translation escape %s

Tags: django, translation

In a template in DJango I need to keep %s as a result of a translation.

Example:

```
{% trans '%s record' %}
```

Needs to translate to:

English:

```
%s record
```

Dutch:

```
%s opname
```

Problem is that in de django.po file, ik heeps adding:

```
#, fuzzy, python-format
msgid "%%s record"
msgstr "%s opname"
```

Correct function code:

```
msgid "%s record"
msgstr "%s opname"
```

But every run on `./manage.py compilemessages` creates the wrong code.

Comment: do you want it to be `%s` or are you gonna use for string formatting?

Comment: I'm using the translated text for javascript printf to add a number to it. So it needs to be %s opname after translation.

Answer (score 1):

If you need variable translation - use `{% blocktrans %}{% endblocktrans %}` instead.

Like this:

```
<p>
{% blocktrans %}
{{ variable }} record
{% endblocktrans %}
</p>
```

Django picks it up and creates correct translation string from it.